# Why am I getting a numpy array as a result

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pandas to process data from a banks database into my clients, the databases being in excel. There is two numbers, however, that come from hand written calculations (Credit card expenses and anomalous products). For some reason I can not understand when I try to include them in the calculations the result is a numpy array (Or at least I believe it is).

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
from passremove import remove_pass
from datetime import date

#importar los excels necesarios
passwd = 'PATA'
aper_file = 'GALICIA resumen 2023-01-31 en proceso.xlsx'

aper_excel = remove_pass(aper_file, passwd)
today = date.today()


#se crean los dataframes necesarios
aper = pd.read_excel(aper_excel, sheet_name='aper', header=1)
fc_apernet = pd.read_excel(aper_excel, sheet_name='FC APERNET', header=0)
fc_apernet = fc_apernet.drop(fc_apernet.index[-1])

#configuramos las variables para armar el dict

fact_banco = aper['Equivalencia Puntos en Pesos $'].sum() / 1.21
fact_tipitos = aper['Total pagado en $'].sum() / 1.21
fact_correo  = aper['Cantidad'].sum()*1573 / 1.21 * -1
venta_productos = fact_banco + fact_tipitos + fact_correo
costo_productos = aper['COSTO TOTAL PESOS'].sum() * -1
anomalos = -3,376.19 
gastos_tarjeta = -15,853.09 
otros_apernet = fc_apernet['Gravado 21'].sum()* - 1
margen_bruto = venta_productos + costo_productos  + otros_apernet + anomalos + gastos_tarjeta
iibb = venta_productos * 0.05 * -1
impuesto_cheque = venta_productos * 1.21 * 0.012 * -1
seg_hig = venta_productos * 0.0098 * -1
util_neta = margen_bruto + iibb + impuesto_cheque + seg_hig     
canjes_facturados = aper['Cantidad'].sum()

resumen_dict = {
    'Categoria': [
                    'Facturacion al banco', 
                    'Facturacion tipitos', 
                    'Facturacion al Correo',
                    'Total Venta Solo Productos',
                    'Costo Productos',
                    'Anomalos',
                    'Otros Gastos Tarjetas de Credito',
                    'Otros Gastos Apernet',
                    'Margen Bruto',
                    'IIBB',
                    'Impuesto al Cheque',
                    'Seg e Hig',
                    'Utilidad Neta Total',
                    'Canjes Facturados'
                ],
    'Valor': [
                    fact_banco,
                    fact_tipitos,
                    fact_correo,
                    venta_productos,
                    costo_productos,
                    anomalos,
                    gastos_tarjeta,
                    otros_apernet,
                    venta_productos + costo_productos  + otros_apernet - anomalos - gastos_tarjeta,
                    iibb,
                    impuesto_cheque,
                    seg_hig,
                    util_neta,
                    canjes_facturados                
    ]
}

resumen_df = pd.DataFrame(resumen_dict)
resumen_df = resumen_df.set_index('Categoria')
resumen_df['Valor'] = resumen_df['Valor'].replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True )



resumen_df.to_excel('Resumen Original {}.xlsx'.format(today))

with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', None):
    display(resumen_df)
```

And here are the results:

| Categoria | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| Facturacion al banco | 631777.892562 |
| Facturacion tipitos | 370955.165289 |
| Facturacion al Correo | -247000.0 |
| Total Venta Solo Productos | 755733.057851 |
| Costo Productos | -624018.7808 |
| Anomalos | (-3, 376.19) |
| Otros Gastos Tarjetas de Credito | (-15, 853.09) |
| Otros Gastos Apernet | -69645.32 |
| Margen Bruto | [62086.9570512395, 60839.6770512395] |
| IIBB | -37786.652893 |
| Impuesto al Cheque | -10973.244 |
| Seg e Hig | -7406.183967 |
| Utilidad Neta Total | [5884.876191735375, 7132.156191735374] |
| Canjes Facturados | 190 |

I have not tried anything because nothing I found online addresses the problem and I am at a loss as to why it is happening.

Comment: The result for Anomalos looks like it's a tuple. The result for Margen Bruto looks like a list. Which one do you think is actually a numpy array? What do you get when you ask for `type(x)` with x replaced by the thing whose type you aren't sure of?

Comment: For the case of anamolos, your problem is where you wrote: `anomalos = -3,376.19`. You can't use a comma as a thousands separator in a Python literal. You can either write `anomalos = -3376.19` or `anomalos = -3_376.19`.

Comment: @ThePhoton <class 'tuple'> <class 'tuple'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> for anomalos, gastos_tarjeta, margen_bruto and util_neta respectively. Why are anomalos and gastos_tarjeta tuples? How can I make them regular floats?

Comment: If you place  tuple in a pandas column it will extend its data type to `object`. As @ThePhoton mentioned the comma used there in `anomalos` results in tuple, not a number. The same for a list. The minimum code for such behaviour is:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,(3,4),[1,13],5]})`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.